# Categorizing items from array with a condition

Tags: java

Basically I have an array of item names which need to be categorized. These items need to get categorized based on condition. For example an item name needs to end with `book`. What would be a good way to do the categorizing?

For example, these categories:

- Books
- Food

Within the array: [Dog book, raw meat, fish, Another sample book]

Comment: Would you post an example of the array and where from you get the conditions ? Are you asking about data structures or comparison functions ?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee - I have just edited my original post. I am asking about data structures.

Comment: you can check the datastructure I posted in my answer. You can either use the class or the datastructure. The class approach is recommended though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LinkedHashMap for something such as this and just iterate through the original,

ex:

```
HashMap<String, String> originalmap = new HashMap<String,String>();

Map<String, String> newmap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

for(Entry<String,String> e : originalmap.entrySet()){
    if(e.getKey().endsWith("book"){
        newmap.add(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
}

//newmap will have all the book entries in the order they were set
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a parent child kind of a relationship , I would suggest you to make two classes :

1. Category
2. Items

   Class Category can be like this

   ```
   public class Category {  
      private ArrayList<Items>;
    //setters and getters  
   }
   ```

Or if you are solely reliant on Data Structures you can use map like this :

```
Map dataStructure = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
String category= "book";
String items[] = {"Dog book", "Another sample book"};
dataStructure.put(category,items);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many methods in String class to do this, You can use endsWith(),contains(),startsWith() methods to see if a String value has some substring and then categories them accordingly.

Comment: I don't think that's what he was asking. He want's to know how to categorize it. I'm sure he already knows String.endsWith().

Comment: @Bug, yes exactly. Instead of having a lot of if else statements.. I'm looking for a better and OO way to do it.

Comment: use a switch then and use different cases to categorize.

Comment: @AmitKothiyal - I cannot use a switch if I want to use String#endsWith or String#contains.